# Saving Canvas Image via asp.net c#

Tags: c#, ajax

I'm trying to save a canvas from a signature pad as a .png using a c# page.  I'm using the following ajax:

```
        var donum =  "xxxxxxxxxx.png"; //imagename
        var usersessionid = "xxxxxxxxxx";

        // Generate the image data
        var Pic = signaturePad.toDataURL();
        Pic = Pic.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

        // Sending the image data to Server
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../ASPFiles/Save_Picture.aspx/UploadPic',
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + Pic + '", "fname" :"' + donum + '", "usersession" : "' + usersessionid + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: OnComplete,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed->' + textStatus);
            }             
        });
```

And the following c#:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static void UploadPic(string imageData, string fname, string usersession)
{


   string maxinactiveinterval = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxUserTimeout"];

    string strConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

    string queryString = (removed)

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    {

        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data. 
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            string Pic_Path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Signatures/"), fname);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Pic_Path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                }
            }

        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

I use this on another website on the same server without any problem, but on this site I just get a "request failed -> parseerror" response.  The web.config does contain:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet" />
      <add name="HttpPost" />
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

although on the working site it runs without those protocols entered.

Answer (score 0):

The `UploadPic` function needs to return a valid JSON to Ajax. Even returning a simple string like `"SUCCESS"` will work.

The `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` protocols are only required for web services (i.e. have the `[WebMethod()]` attribute).

Comment: I tried this, and still doesn't work.  But the code as it is does work on another site on the same server, so I believe it's something unique to the site.